# jdbc connection error: not associated with a managed connection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jboss

My application is trowing the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is not associated with a managed connection.org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@4fe91321
```

This is happening in production I'm not able to get this problem in development and for that I'm not able to solve it.
The root of the exception is code line `dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);`

From what I was able to find in the web, the cause for this can be:

1. Over jdbc connection, a jboss connection is wrapped but the wrapper is empty. The original jdbc connection inside is no longer there.
2. JDBC Connection is already closed and trying to work with close connection is the reason why I'm getting this exception.
3. The transaction manger detects transaction that is taking to long then the transaction timeout.

So if someone can point me what is the problem because I'm not able to get this problem in mine development environment.
Also what logs can I add that will help me detect the problem in production - I'm using Java, JBoss, Postgre.

I'have enable connection close monitoringa, and also to add is that the issue is not consistent

Comment: Looks like you're not closing your resources after using them i.e. `resultSet.close(); preparedStatement.close(); connection.close();`. If this is well handled in your application, then there must be a third agent that is interfering with this process.

Comment: As user3754761 said, change your jdbc driver of setup.

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved the issue.

It's my jndi driver not compatible with the latest java frameworks.

I'm using Oracle db and ojdbc6, and i download a latest ojdbc6 from maven repository and replace the old same name jar file. It works like bird now.

Comment: Thank you. You made my day. Same issue here with JBoss 5.1 and ORACLE 11g. Downloading latest version from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc6/12.1.0.1-atlassian-hosted fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an EJB, it's possible that your Stateless Session Bean Pool is not big enough. The connection can't find an associated thread.

**Maybe** you have an extended Transaction for a not Stateful Session Bean, wich is **maybe** not a good idea.